# Converting a sed string to PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a regexp I'm using with sed, but now I need to make it work in PHP also. I can't use system calls as they are disabled.

```
$ cat uglynumber.txt:
Ticket number : 303905694, FOO:BAR:BAR: Some text
Case ID:123,456,789:Foobar - Some other text
303867970;[FOOBAR] Some text goes here
Case Ref: 303658850 - Some random text here - host.tld #78854w
```

```
$ cat uglynumbers.txt | sed "s/[, ]//g;s/.*\([0-9]\{9\}\).*/\1/g"
303905694
123456789
303867970
303658850
```

So, how to do the same with PHP?

I found one example like this, but I can't inject that regexp into that.

```
if (preg_match("/.../", $line, $matches)) {
  echo "Match was found";
  echo $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific SED example is obviously 2 regular expressions, 1 being replacing the commas, and one being technically grabbing the 9 digit continuous numbers.

The first half of your SED string is best fit with the `preg_replace()` function.

```
//`sed s/regex/replace_value/flags`

preg_replace('/regex/flags', 'replace_value', $input);
```

The second half of your SED string would be a `preg_match_all()`:

```
//`sed ...;s/regex/\1/flags`

$matches_array = array();
preg_match_all('/regex/flags', $input, &$matches_array);
```

So your specific code will look something like:

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('uglynumbers.txt');

$input = preg_replace('/[, ]/m','', $input);

$matches = array();
//No need for the .* or groupings, just match all occurrences of [0-9]{9}
if( preg_match_all('/[0-9]{9}/m', $input, $matches) )
{
    //...
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

---

It looks like `g` is an SED modifier meaning match all lines. `preg_match_all()` should already takes care of this modifier but `m` seems like an appropriate replacement as per the manual on [PCRE modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: I have this one problem with every test:

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' in ...

Comment: @boogie: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php I don't know SED that well so find the appropriate modifiers there

Comment: @boogie: it looks like 'g' means match all in SED, in this case you don't need it, though you might want to throw down an 'm' for multiline

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) instead of `preg_match()`.  `grep` is to `sed` what `preg_match` is to `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace()` is the function you are looking for. You can pass an array of patterns and replace parameters

```
$pattern = array('/[, ]/','/.*\([0-9]\{9\}\).*/');
$replace = array('','$1');

foreach($lines as $line) {
   $newlines[] = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $line);
}
```

Comment: There is no `g` modifier in PHP. `preg_replace()` replaces everything by default and has an optional parameter to limit this.